# Error wile building android 6.0 marshmallow

Tags: android, ubuntu, building

I am building aosp 6.0 for my nexus and I am getting these errors and the build stops exactly right there no matter for which device I build

I have skipped some code because stack overflow didn't allow to post them. I am using ubuntu 14.04 and have built roms with this previously
and to mention I got this error while building as also find: `frameworks/base/docs/html-ndk': No such file or directory
 Synced the source thrice but file is not getting downloaded

> including ./sdk/sdklauncher/Android.mk ... including
>   ./system/bt/Android.mk ... including ./system/core/Android.mk ...
>   including ./system/extras/Android.mk ... including
>   ./system/gatekeeper/Android.mk ... including
>   ./system/keymaster/Android.mk ... including
>   ./system/media/alsa_utils/Android.mk ... including
>   ./system/media/audio_route/Android.mk ... including
>   ./system/media/audio_utils/Android.mk ... including
>   ./system/media/camera/src/Android.mk ... including
>   ./system/media/camera/tests/Android.mk ... including
>   ./system/media/radio/src/Android.mk ... including
>   ./system/netd/Android.mk ... including
>   ./system/security/keystore-engine/Android.mk ... including
>   ./system/security/keystore/Android.mk ... including
>   ./system/security/softkeymaster/Android.mk ... including
>   ./system/vold/Android.mk ... including
>   ./tools/external/fat32lib/Android.mk ... No private recovery resources
>   for TARGET_DEVICE deb make: *** No rule to make target 'j-8'.  Stop.
>
> make failed to build some targets (01:51 (mm:ss))
>
> CJMod@buildserver:~/marshmallow$

Answer (score 1):

Your main error is in the following line:

> No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE deb make: *** No rule to make target 'j-8'

There's no rule to create target j-8 instead you should do:

> make -j8

Instead, you probably did:

> make j-8